# Set darkMode across multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, local-storage, toggle, darkmode

I have two html pages(index.htm and details.htm). Whenever I enable dark Mode in details.html, it is retained in the index.html without any issues, but when I go to the details page from the index.html page the darkMode gets disabled.

I'm using local storage for enabling and disabling the darkMode.

My javascript code:

```
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
const toggleBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#mode");

document.body.classList.add('lightMode');

function enableDarkMode() {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
    document.body.classList.add('darkMode');
    document.body.classList.remove('lightMode');
}

function disableDarkMode() {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null)
    document.body.classList.remove('darkMode');
    document.body.classList.add('lightMode');
}

toggleBtn.forEach(btn => {
    if(darkMode === 'enabled') {
        enableDarkMode();
    }
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode')
        if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
            enableDarkMode()
        } else {
            disableDarkMode();
        }
    });
})
```

css code :

```
.lightMode {
  --background-color: white;
  --textColor: black;
  --borderColor: black;
  --shadowColor: grey;
  --card: white;
  --span: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.459);
  --footer: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  --element: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  --tagColor: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.darkMode {
  --background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  --textColor: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
  --borderColor: white;
  --shadowColor: black;
  --card: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  --span: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.459);
  --footer: rgb(56, 56, 56);
  --element: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.493);
  --tagColor: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

My css only consists of a few custom variables with the same name for both themes.

A for my html the body doesn't have any classes. classes for the body tag are added through javascript

Is there a way to set the darkMode to be enabled to all pages unless the the user changes it himself everytime he visits the page?

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to see if the `darkMode` class has been added to the body element? This will help identify if the issue is in your CSS or the JS.

Comment: @j-petty, it works perfectly fine when going to the index page from the details page but the issue arises when I got to the details page from the index page.                                                here's a link to see the issue more clearly - https://rithish288.github.io/Periodic-Table/

Comment: Thanks for the link. The class isn't being set on the body, meaning the issue lives in the JS. I wonder if it's the order you're including the JS files in your body. I noticed on the home page you've got them in the `head` but in the details page the scripts are at the end of the `body`. I'd suggest making this consistent across the two pages and see if that alters the result.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem in your JS, you may have not put the class name 'darkMode' in your body tag of html. One thing is for sure that problem is not the script, but css or html. Look your code for these two again.

Comment: By the way, your site/periodic table is working fine for me, I don't see the issue of dark mode in it. It's just that I have to enable it at all pages again and again

Comment: yeah that's the problem. The user has to click again and again to enable it.

Comment: Answer me one thing - have you created two different html pages or not? If you have both pages inside one html body then, this problem might get solved. Like one `<section></section/> `for periodic table and other `<section></section/>` for the animation or detail page you said.

Comment: yeah, there are two separate html files